# ControlTemplate on Style WPF / MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to figure out how to define a ControlTemplate for all the textboxes I have in my UserControl, I have tried several things but doesn't seems to work.

What I need is bind the KeyBinding to a Command:

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SaveConfigCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

this is working so far, but adding the same snippet to all the textboxes it's not a good practice. So I tried to put it on the Styles but I get NullReferenceException

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding}"/>
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SaveConfigCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter.InputBindings>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Edit for future references:
Although the answer is correct, I would like to point out that the `TemplateBinding Text` it is not enough when you are already binding the Text property in the control, as the `TemplateBinding` is only a `OneWay` Binding, you have to use the following:

`Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TemplateBinding is used for binding to the control properties within the template definition. Further put your InputBindings to the TextBox.

```
<Style x:Key="tbxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}">
                                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SaveConfigCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}}"/>
                                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem}" Style="{StaticResource tbxStyle}">
```

Comment: Doesn't work, got another (different) exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Infinite loop in references found while processing the Template for an element named '' of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'.'

Comment: You are right, I forgot to include the `Style="{StaticResource tbxStyle}`.
Any reason you have to specify the name in order to make it work? I want this to apply in all the TextBoxes, thats why I used the TargetType.

Comment: The problem is, that you use TextBox-Element in Template for TextBox.

Comment: I see, understood, I also realize that I have to include {TemplateBinding} to all the properties that are not the default for TextBoxes.

Comment: I have edited my question with more info, since the solution is not fully working as the `TemplateBinding` is OneWay binding, you need to do like:
`Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`